How to create a loading effect in react image turntable
I am working on this library called react-image-turntable in my project, Now how can i insert a loading effect or progress bar while the images are being loaded? because currently I am only seeing empty page while the images is being loaded.
return (
    <ReactImageTurntable
      images={images}
      autoRotate={{ disabled: rotationDisabled, interval: 200 }}
      onPointerDown={() => setRotationDisabled(true)}
      onPointerUp={() => setRotationDisabled(false)}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      onKeyUp={() => setRotationDisabled(false)}
    />
  );

thanks
